# Java: Running transaction in multithreaded environment

Tags: multithreading, spring, hibernate, junit, executorservice

We are launching a website that will have a very heavy volume for a short period of time. It is basically giving tickets. The code is written in Java, Spring & Hibernate. I want to mimic the high volume by spawning multiple threads and trying to get the ticket using JUnit test case. The problem is that in my DAO class the code just simply dies after I begin transaction. I mean there is no error trace in the log file or anything like that. Let me give some idea about the way my code is.

DAO code:

```
@Repository("customerTicketDAO")
public class CustomerTicketDAO extends BaseDAOImpl {// BaseDAOImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport

public void saveCustomerTicketUsingJDBC(String customerId) {
  try{
      getSession().getTransaction().begin(); //NOTHING HAPPENS AFTER THIS LINE OF CODE
      // A select query
      Query query1 = getSession().createSQLQuery("my query omitted on purpose");
      .
      .
      // An update query
      Query query2 = getSession().createSQLQuery("my query omitted on purpose");
      getSession().getTransaction().commite();
   } catch (Exception e) {
   }
}
```

Runnable code:

```
public class InsertCustomerTicketRunnable implements Runnable {

@Autowired
private CustomerTicketDAO customerTicketDAO;    

 public InsertCustomerTicketRunnable(String customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
}     

 @Override
public void run() {
    if (customerTicketDAO != null) {
        customerTicketDAO.saveCustomerTicketUsingJDBC(customerId); 
    }
}
}
```

JUnit method:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"file:src/test/resources/applicationContext-test.xml"})
public class DatabaseTest {
  @Before
public void init() {
    sessionFactory = (SessionFactory)applicationContext.getBean("sessionFactory");
    Session session = SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(sessionFactory, true);
    TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(sessionFactory, new SessionHolder(session));

    customerTicketDAO = (CustomerTicketDAO)applicationContext.getBean("customerTicketDAO");
}

@After
public void end() throws Exception {
    SessionHolder sessionHolder = (SessionHolder) TransactionSynchronizationManager.unbindResource(sessionFactory);
    SessionFactoryUtils.closeSession(session);
  }

  @Test
public void saveCustomerTicketInMultipleThreads () throws Exception  {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NTHREDS);

    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
        executor.submit(new InsertCustomerTicketRunnable(i));
    }

    // This will make the executor accept no new threads
    // and finish all existing threads in the queue
    executor.shutdown();
    // Wait until all threads are finish
    executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

I see no data being inserted into the database. Can someone please point me as to where I am going wrong?

Thanks
Raj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SessionFactory` is thread safe but `Session` is not. So my guess is that you need to call `SessionFactoryUtils.getSession()` from within each thread, so that each thread gets its own instance. You are currently calling it from the main thread, so all children threads try to share the same instance.

Comment: I will definitely try your suggestion and let you know. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: This is it. I have marked your response as an answer to the question. Thank you so much David.

Answer (score 0):

Naughty, naughty!

```
public void saveCustomerTicketUsingJDBC(String customerId) {
  try {
      getSession().getTransaction().begin(); //NOTHING HAPPENS AFTER THIS LINE OF CODE
      .
      .
   } catch (Exception e) {
   }
}
```

You should never (well, hardly ever) have an empty `catch` block, if there is a problem you will find that your code 'just simply dies' with no log messages. Oh look, that's what's happening ;)

At the very minimum you should log the exception, that will go a long way towards you helping you find what the problem is (and from there, the solution).

Comment: I omitted that piece of code just for conciseness. I do have a logger in the exception block.